# Forge Design Automation for Revit fails: Error: The path is empty. (Parameter 'path')

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I get a failedInstruction error when I post my workitem. Inside the error report, it seems like it's failing for: "Error: The path is empty. (Parameter 'path')". I am not quite sure if that refers to the Revit file path, or to the appbundle path. How is the 'path' variable defined for both Revit input file and the AppBundle? And why is it missing in my case?

Error: The path is empty. (Parameter 'path')

Here is the full error report:

```
[05/23/2022 20:29:06] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  " \"$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[rvtFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[Revit2ProtoExporter].path)\"\" "
]
"Settings":{
  "dasreportfaileduploadoptional": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"fa2e89a3c85f41a79fd88260f3226208"
"ActivityId":"WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI.Revit2ProtoExporterActivity+OV"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Revit_2022!84"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI.Revit2ProtoExporter!72"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "rvtFile": {
    "localName": "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:kRW0jj8ZUtU7QNO0DXCukH2NDJ4=",
    "headers": {
      "authorization": "Masked:lzecgHABfhiJUIYpcsTkOjZZWFo="
    }
  },
  "params": {
    "localName": "params.json",
    "url": "data:application/json,{'ViewName': {3D}}"
  },
  "result": {
    "localName": "result.avr",
    "url": "https://staging-appliedvrabs-pa.sandbox.googleapis.com/Masked:CUBqvnZeP60rTw+WOsCYg+6qY4w=",
    "headers": {
      "authorization": "Masked:nrdnIil6wykGG+lQSU3nx9c04hc="
    },
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI\"},\"scope\":\"code:all data:write data:read bucket:create bucket:delete\",\"expires_in\":3599,\"client_id\":\"WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI\"}",
      "x-ads-gateway-secret": "Masked:F6VCvje5cIP0zOGCxgARjmSopQI="
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 10800,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 5000
}
[05/23/2022 20:29:06] Starting work item fa2e89a3c85f41a79fd88260f3226208
[05/23/2022 20:29:06] Start download phase.
[05/23/2022 20:29:06] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/47f2a6e6-4349-4a9e-b066-14019b2d95ff.rvt'
[05/23/2022 20:29:06] Embedded resource [{'ViewName': {3D}}] is saved as file: T:\Aces\Jobs\fa2e89a3c85f41a79fd88260f3226208\params.json.
[05/23/2022 20:29:07] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/47f2a6e6-4349-4a9e-b066-14019b2d95ff.rvt,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\fa2e89a3c85f41a79fd88260f3226208\rac_basic_sample_project.rvt,BytesDownloaded=18739200,Duration=1031ms
[05/23/2022 20:29:07] End download phase successfully.
[05/23/2022 20:29:07] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[05/23/2022 20:29:07] Error: The path is empty. (Parameter 'path')
[05/23/2022 20:29:07] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[05/23/2022 20:29:07] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[05/23/2022 20:29:07] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI/fa2e89a3c85f41a79fd88260f3226208/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=48600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHsaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCICFX1xarqQIWj10LZbH8Ogb1swNKKEnd7t3VJTNYx%2FHtAiEAlfPN0Kaa8Yjn7RsU9ZkPzYTJo5kWYmMdSpnwbqaKnM4qmwIIZBADGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDNF%2BhEZNhXEO0%2FTIwCr4AV3eSxj8u0wq%2FcvREh15dwcQfTm2kXP95obEvnxcjWGAIM2NSaQ8w1KOBrXALQQ4NnQMMyGtcgKAk1GJ6gyn1T51PWw7a5GJEqO02yNWFTNeEANXCLe%2F55CQ1RyksuAVIgwcXBmu%2FHmSfSVLpk39fTuqa%2Fa3v4V%2FpniYHVx2fXpaKQF0z2E3pru%2BC5kj6RPG4%2BMoAdISMp9wVYCSLOOUTAZB%2FJ0LZDTxqBgYOWjlnIN%2B7IU2KgDdxS0W98uQBYhc%2FroQGpObXtY1FnRNKpdBjRAU4QaMN6jveWaw%2FzwDohbqeECZcVc9xUv3uwdyklCB%2FzlKzIy8MIWoMLWzr5QGOpoB%2B0luYyTRiH4a9WXVDp7XaclmwJgAIuh51jahpYov5JwufcGO8%2FpSBp32G5vluCyVQ%2BoovdvGAMRoemwlx8rFDsomUR9V3TNNwEk4pyCz%2BUO2l5MUAkh4Cg%2BtSiYGHVcm995rTdn4C8u6AaoQ6U5ebbDd4Nd00O9u2pE2InYzsJwWn2%2BD0cr%2FlAvYWa2qG%2Fe77GcgwzYiFnDhAw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3O2XOGJGQ/20220523/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220523T202906Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=cbc26867c48d0f8eb8e21c15b321979b38bb997e54ddd6be481ae5949c25d734",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2022-05-23T20:29:06.4788749Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2022-05-23T20:29:06.7267659Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2022-05-23T20:29:07.8697987Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2022-05-23T20:29:07.8711572Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 18739218
  },
  "id": "fa2e89a3c85f41a79fd88260f3226208"
}
```

Here is the response that I get when I publish the activity:

```
 {'commandLine': [' "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i "$(args[rvtFile].path)" /al "$(appbundles[Revit2ProtoExporter].path)"" '], 'parameters': {'rvtFile': {'verb': 'get', 'description': 'Input', 'required': True, 'localName': '$(rvtFile)'}, 'params': {'verb': 'get', 'required': True, 'localName': 'params.json'}, 'result': {'verb': 'put', 'description': 'Result', 'required': True, 'localName': 'result.avr'}}, 'id': 'WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI.Revit2ProtoExporterActivity', 'engine': 'Autodesk.Revit+2022', 'appbundles': ['WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI.Revit2ProtoExporter+OV'], 'description': 'Export Geometry', 'version': 76}
```

What's missing from my workitem that's causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commandline in the post seems not correct still, it was read as
`[{ "commandLine": [ " \"$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[rvtFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[Revit2ProtoExporter].path)\"\" " ]`, which could not be parsed correctly.

Could you try define the commandline to be

```
{ 'commandLine': [ '$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i "$(args[rvtFile].path)" /al "$(appbundles[Revit2ProtoExporter].path)"']...
```